# Getting a Total

Tags: jquery, arrays, codeigniter, function, variables

Okay, The challenge is relatively small but it's a fly buzzing around my head.
Take a look in jQuery at $("#list_total"+table_number).text("$"+grand_total[table_number].toFixed(2));

What I've tried to do is grand_total[table_number] += sub_total; but I keep getting NaN.

**CSS**

```
    .guest_table
    {
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 30px;
    width: 280px;
    }

    h1
    {
    text-align: center;
    }

    table
    {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 425px;
    }

    table, tr
    {
    border: 5px solid black;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px; /* future proofing */
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
    }

     tr
    {
    height: 65px;
    }

    .submit
    {
    text-align: center;
    }

    .input
    {
    border: none;
    background: #fff url(../images/rounded-corner.png) no-repeat left top;
    background-size:185px 37px;
    width: 160px;
    padding: 10px;
    }

    .input:focus
    {
    background-color:  #ffff33 ;
    }

    #submit_form
    {
    border: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }

    .error
    {
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 25%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }

    .list_total
    {
    display:  inline-block;
    padding-left: 5px;
    }

    #option_list
    {
    width: 25%;
    }

    #already_paid
    {
    text-align: center;
    }

   input[type=submit]:hover,input[type=reset]:hover
    {
    background-color: #8F5B00;
    color: white;
    }

    button, input[type=submit]
    {
    margin-left: 10px;
    }

    button:hover
    {
    background-color: #8F5B00;
    color: white;
    }
```

**Codeigniter View**

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php
$total_guests = count($results);
$attributes = array(
    'id' => 'submit_form'
);

echo form_open('main/form_validation/options');
?>

<div id="center">
    <?php
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        ?>
        <table class="guest_table" id="guest_<?php echo $result->id; ?>">
            <th>
    <?php echo $result->full_name; ?>    
            </th>
            <tr id="option_list">
                <td>

                    <?php
                    $b = $price2 > 0 ? " $" . $price2 : "N/A";

                    $day = array(
                        array(
                            'name' => 'friday_performance_' . $result->id,
                            'id' => 'friday_performance' . $result->id,
                            'value' => 'friday_performance'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'name' => 'friday_banquet_' . $result->id,
                            'id' => 'friday_banquet' . $result->id,
                            'value' => 'friday_banquet'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'name' => 'saturday_' . $result->id,
                            'id' => 'saturday' . $result->id,
                            'value' => 'saturday'
                        ),
                    );


                    $meal_pref = array(
                        array(
                            'name' => 'meal_' . $result->id,
                            'id' => 'chicken',
                            'value' => 'chicken'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'name' => 'meal_' . $result->id,
                            'id' => 'fish',
                            'value' => 'fish'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'name' => 'meal_' . $result->id,
                            'id' => 'vegetarian',
                            'value' => 'vegetarian'
                        ),
                    );


                    echo form_checkbox($day[0]);
                    ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    Friday Performance <?php echo " $" . $price1; ?><br>

                    <?php echo form_checkbox($day[1]);
                    ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;Friday Banquet <?php echo $b; ?><br>
                    <div class="meal_choice"  id='meal_choice<?php echo $result->id; ?    >'>
                        <?php
                        echo form_radio($meal_pref[0]);
                        ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;Chicken <br>
                        <?php echo form_radio($meal_pref[1]);
                        ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;Fish <br>
                        <?php echo form_radio($meal_pref[2]);
                        ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;Vegetarian<br>

                    </div>
    <?php echo form_checkbox($day[2]); ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;Saturday Workshop w/lunch <?php echo " $" . $price3; ?><br>
                    <br><br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Total:<div class="list_total" id="list_total<?php echo $result->id; ?>"></div>
                </td>

        </table>

<?php } ?>
</div>
<div class="submit">
    <?php
    echo ("<input type='hidden' name='email' value=" . $this->session->userdata('email') . ">");

    $data = array(
        'name' => 'submit',
        'id' => 'submit',
        'value' => 'Complete Form',
        'type' => 'submit'
    );

    echo form_submit($data);
    echo form_button('exit', 'Exit');
    ?>

</div>
<?php
echo form_close();
?>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".list_total").text("$0.00");
    $(".meal_choice").hide();
    var total_attending = (<?php echo $total_guests; ?> + 1);

    $("[name='exit']").click(function(){
        window.location.href='<?php echo base_url(); ?>/main/logout';
    });

    var table_number = 0;
    $('.guest_table').click(function(){
        var table_id = $(this).attr('id');
        table_number = parseInt(table_id.charAt(table_id.length-1));
    });
    var grand_total=[];
    grand_total[table_number]=0.00;

    $(':checkbox').change(function(){

        switch($(this).attr('id'))
        {
            case 'friday_performance' + table_number:
                var sub_total= 0.00;
                sub_total =  parseInt(friday_performance());
                grand_total[table_number] += sub_total;

                $("#list_total"+table_number).text("$"+ grand_total[table_number].toFixed(2));
                break;

            case 'friday_banquet' + table_number:
                var sub_total= 0.00;
                sub_total =  parseInt(friday_banquet());
                grand_total[table_number] += sub_total;
                $("#list_total"+table_number).text("$"+ grand_total[table_number].toFixed(2));
                break;
            case 'saturday' + table_number:
                var sub_total= 0.00;
                sub_total  +=  parseInt(saturday());
                grand_total[table_number] = sub_total;
                $("#list_total"+table_number).text("$"+ grand_total[table_number].toFixed(2));
                break;

        }
    });

    function friday_performance ()
    {
        if ( $("#friday_performance"+table_number).is(":checked"))
        {
            var price1 = <?php echo $price1; ?>;
            return price1;
        }else  if ( $("#friday_performance"+table_number).not(":checked"))
        {
            var price1 = 0;
            return price1;
        }
    }

    function friday_banquet ()
    {
        if ($("#friday_banquet"+table_number).is(":checked"))
        {
            $("#meal_choice"+table_number).show("slow");
            var price2 = <?php echo $price2; ?>;
            return price2;
        }else if ($("#friday_banquet"+table_number).not(":checked"))
        {
            $("#meal_choice"+table_number).hide("slow");
            $('input:radio').prop("checked",false);
            var price2 = 0;
            return price2;
        }
    }

    function saturday()
    {
        if ( $("#saturday"+table_number).is(":checked"))
        {
            var price3 = <?php echo $price3; ?>;
            return price3;
        }else  if ( $("#saturday"+table_number).not(":checked"))
        {
            var price3 = 0;
            return price3;
        }

    }

    $("#submit").click(function(){
        alert("Got it!");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: you need to make sure all the variables you are using with `+` should be the same type. If you are trying to add integers make sure you use the `parseInt` method and if you are using string then use `toFixed`.

Answer (score 1):

You can debug this easily.

Open the console in your browser (F12).

Type the following:

```
table_number

sub_total

grand_total[table_number]
```

That will tell you what you need - one is not a number. If necessary, edit your question mentioning the values of the above variables in your console and we will help further.

Being comfortable with using the console in your browser will help you develop client-side web apps.

Comment: Thanks...I double checked with firebug...shows table_number is a number (no quotes around the number) as well as sub_total.

Comment: Sorry, timed out on previous comment...anyways...   Thanks...I double checked with firebug...shows table_number is a number (no quotes around the number) as well as sub_total.    The odd thing is, when I mouseover grand_total...I'm getting [0, NaN] even thought grand_total[table_number] += sub_total; <--- sub_total is showing a value.

Answer (score 1):

You have initialized the `grand_total` variable but you should also initialize `grand_total[table_number]` i.e. the value with the index before you start adding anything to it.

Consider modifying the following lines:

```
$(':checkbox').change(function(){

    switch($(this).attr('id'))
    {
```

to this:

```
$(':checkbox').change(function(){

    if (typeof (grand_total[table_number]) === "undefined") {
        grand_total[table_number] = 0;
    }

    switch($(this).attr('id'))
    {
```